# searching Korean values in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column company in Korean language.

```
select * from TableA where Company like '%(주)지씨에스씨%'
```

but when i run the query i get 2 records like

```
Company       ID 
(?)??????     1452
(?)????????   1456
```

Now i checked the table A , Column "Company" is defined as NVarchar. So using n'%(주)지씨에스씨%' 
is not correct and is also giving syntax error.  Now i'm confused which record is equal to my search value .
I have used :  `select * from TableA where Company= '(주)지씨에스씨'`
which is returning 1 values in question marks .BUt i want to be sure , i want to see what that question mark means. 
Can someone tell me how to decode this question marks ?? What are the real values they are storing in form of Question mark??

Comment: Prefix Unicode literal strings with N to denote Unicode and make sure parameters are `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`. It looks like this was not done when the rows were inserted, resulting in loss of the character data.

Comment: `n'%(주)지씨에스씨%'` will generate an error. The notational character must be uppercase.